# Project runs in Eclipse, but not from command line : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with Maven and Dom4J

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, runtime-error, dom4j

I made a small sample project to test things out and came across something that I found weird.
I made a new Maven Project in Eclipse with some code that pokes around in XML files using Dom4J.
It runs fine as long as I only start the App from withing Eclipse, however when I want to start the jar that maven packaged for me I get this Error:

```
avalon% java -jar target/avalon.launcher-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3035)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3005)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

There must be something wrong with my setup. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>de.oliverconzen</groupId>
  <artifactId>avalon.launcher</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>avalon</name>
  <description>Simple cli based game written in Java</description>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>de.oliverconzen.avalon.launcher.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Of course, second after I post this, I found an answer. The dependencies don't get bundled for execution. If they are not bundled, the jars of dependencies have to be in the same folder (?).

Anyway, this helped me:

[How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)